# Bedeutung "...kann einem echt die Spucke wegbleiben"

Tags: translation, idiom

Ich glaube, der Begriff "die Spucke wegbleiben" ist idiomatisch.

Könnte mir bitte jemand diese zwei Sachen erklären:

1. Was der Begriff bedeutet, mit Beispielen bitte
2. Warum man "einem", also Dativ, benutzt. 
   Kann ich z.B. auch "mir" benutzen oder muss man "einem" sagen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Redewendung `jmdm. bleibt die Spucke weg` wird nicht nur im wörtlich-physiologischen Sinne gebraucht - das Ausbleiben des Speichelflusses bei Aufregung, Angst oder Schreck -, sondern hat auch eine übertragene Bedeutung. Sie bezeichnet eine Reaktion der Überraschung, insbesondere auf unverfrorenes Verhalten.

Beispiele sind etwa:

> Bei diesem Angebot bleibt einem echt die Spucke weg!
>
> Was für eine Unverschämtheit! Da bleibt mir echt die Spucke weg!

`einem` ist hier der Dativ von `man`. Der Dativ wir hier vom Verb verlangt. Es ist syntaktisch auch korrekt, `mir` (als Dativ von `ich`) zu verwenden - das ändert aber natürlich die Bedeutung.

Answer (score 4):

"Die Spucke wegbleiben" ist tatsächlich eine feststehende Redewendung und bedeutet, dass einem in einem Moment des Schrecks die Spucke wegbleibt. Siehe [diese Quelle](http://www.sprichwoerter-redewendungen.de/redewendungen/die-spucke-wegbleiben/)

Zum Dativ: Wem oder was bleibt die Spucke weg -> Dativ

Jedem (jeder Person) kann die Spucke wegbleiben, auch mir.

Aussprüche wie "da bleibt mir die Spucke weg" oder "ihm blieb die Spucke weg" sind verständlich und werden auch benutzt. Das allgemeine "einem bleibt die Spucke weg" ist aber viel häufiger anzutreffen. "Einem" steht hier für "irgendeinem" im Sinne von "allen" (aber nicht gleichzeitig, deshalb nicht "allen blieb die Spucke weg"; das wäre ein denkbarer Sonderfall, wenn alle aus einer Gruppe sich erschreckt haben).